# Use residues to find $\int_0^\pi \frac{d\theta}{5+3\cos\theta}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, residue-calculus

I am trying to use residues to find $\int_0^\pi \frac{d\theta}{5+3\cos\theta}$.

My thoughts:

Letting $z=e^{i\theta}$ we get $dz=ie^{i\theta}$.  Then, $\int_0^\pi \frac{d\theta}{5+3\cos\theta}=\frac{1}{5}\int_{|z|=1}\frac{dz}{iz(1+\frac{3}{5}(\frac{z+z^{-1}}{2}))}=-2i\int_{|z|=1}\frac{dz}{3z^2+10z+3}$.
Now, using the quadratic formula, we get that the integral becomes $-2i\int_{|z|=1}\frac{dz}{(z+3)(3z+1)}$.  So, now we will compute the residue at $z=-\frac{1}{3}$ only since $z=3$ is outside of our circle.  The residue is equal to $\frac{3}{8}$, and so the integral is equal to $(2\pi i)(-2i)(\frac{3}{8})=\frac{3\pi}{2}$.  But, this integral, I believe should actually be equal to $\frac{\pi}{4}$ based on Wolfram.

I am wondering if I did something wrong, or (hopefully not) is it just some silly algebra mistake somewhere.  Any thoughts, suggestions, etc. are always appreciated!  Thank you.

Comment: there are two algebra mistakes - the residue has an extra $1/3$ as $\frac{z+1/3}{3z+1} \to 1/3$ and the original integral is $[0,\pi]$ so you need another $1/2$ to make it full circle (which is indeed legitimate by symmetry)

Comment: @Conrad I see that I made an algebra mistake, but shouldn't the residue be $\frac{9}{8}$ as $\lim_{z\rightarrow -\frac{1}{3}}\frac{z+\frac{1}{3}}{(3z+1)(z+3)}=\lim_{z\rightarrow -\frac{1}{3}}\frac{1}{z+3}$?

Comment: $\frac{z+1/3}{3z+1} =1/3$

Comment: @Conrad Okay, I see that, but what about the $z+3$ part?  Even though $z=-3$ isn't going to be considered, don't we still need to worry about that factor?  So, we would get $\frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{\frac{8}{9}}=\frac{3}{8}$?

Comment: Not sure what you are talking about $1/(-1/3+3)=3/8$ not $9/8$ so multiplying with the $1/3$ from the $3z+1$ vs $z+1/3$ gives you $1/8$ as the residue at $-1/3$ is just $\lim_{z\rightarrow -\frac{1}{3}}\frac{z+\frac{1}{3}}{(3z+1)(z+3)}=1/8$

Comment: @Conrad I see my (quite persistent) stupid mistake.  I appreciate the time.  I am sorry for turning this from a complex integral problem to a basic algebra problem :)

Comment: no problem - you can always double-check with the simple fraction decomposition if in doubt and here it is $1/8(3/(3z+1)-1/(z+3)$ so the limit is $1/8$ as the numerator $3$ gives precisely the denominator when multiplied by $z+1/3$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$I = \int_0^\pi \frac{d\theta}{5+3\cos\theta}$$

I want the range to be $0$ to $2\pi$ so I will apply the substitution $\tau = \theta / 2$.

$$I = \int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{d\tau}{10+6\cos\tau}$$

Now I can apply my Residue Theorem lemma (from Freitag):

[image]

In our case $$f(z) = \frac{1}{i z}\frac{1}{10 + \tfrac{1}{2}6(z + \frac{1}{z})} = \frac{1}{i}\frac{1}{3z^2 + 10z + 3} = \frac{-i}{(z + 3)(3z + 1)} = \frac{-i}{3 (z + 3)(z + \tfrac{1}{3})}$$

There are two simple poles at $z_1=-3$ and $z_2=-\tfrac{1}{3}$ let's calculate the residues:

- $\operatorname{Res}(f;z_1) = \frac{-i}{3 \cdot (z_1 + \tfrac{1}{3})} = i/8$
- $\operatorname{Res}(f;z_2) = \frac{-i}{3 \cdot (z_2 + 3)} = -i/8$

we will only use the $z_2$ residue as $z_1$ lies outside $\mathbb E$.

So $$I = 2 \pi i \cdot - i / 8 = \pi / 4$$

Comment: This is wrong (though gives the right answer!): substituting $\tau=\theta/2$ takes the range of integration to $0\leq\tau\leq\pi/2$. And the transformed integrand is wrong too.